# display image and run script for fifteen seconds

Tags: php, javascript, jquery

This is very similar to a question I asked the other day but my page code has become significantly more complicated and I need to revisit it. I've been using the following code:

```
$('#myLink').click(function() {
  $('#myImg').attr('src', 'newImg.jpg');
  setTimeout(function() { $('#myImg').attr('src', 'oldImg.jpg'); }, 15000);
});
```

To replace an image for a set period of time (15 seconds) when the link is clicked, then after 15 seconds, revert to the original image.

However now, I'd like to run a snippet of javascript as well when the link is clicked (in addition to replacing the image), and only when the link is clicked (it's related to the 15 second image) and then have the js code disappear as well after the 15 seconds...however I'm not sure how to have jquery send js code into the page...Basically I just want jQuery to "echo" this code onto the page underneath the 15 second while I am there, but I don't know how jquery formats this "echo".

Does this question make sense?

```
  interval = 500;
  imgsrc = "webcam/image.jpg";

  function Refresh() {
     tmp = new Date(); 
     tmp = "?" + tmp.getTime();
     document.images["image1"].src = imgsrc + tmp;
     setTimeout("Refresh()", interval);
  }
```

Refresh();
It's script for a webcam. Basically it takes a new picture every half a second and replaces it on the page. You must forgive me, I'm new to jquery, I don't know how to make this script work in a jquery context.

i'm sorry, I'm explaining badly. This is what I need to happen, step by step:

1. User comes to the page and there is a static image that says "Click here to view webcam"
2. User clicks image
3. Image is replaced by live webcam image, which is refreshed every .5 seconds by the second script in my question.
4. After 15 seconds the live webcam reverts back to the static image saying "click here to view webcam"

It is ONLY during that 15 second interval that I wan the webcam refresh script running, otherwise it's wasting bandwidth on an element that isn't even shown. Sorry for the confusion.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

this should do the trick for you... (though you probably could try detecting if they have left the page (I can't give you any suggestions on how to do that))

```
var myLink = $('#myLink');
var myImg = $('#myImg');

myLink.click(function() {
   // makes sure this can only run once per 15sec
   myLink.attr('disabled', 'disabled');

   var start = new Date();
   var interval = null;

   function refresh() {
      var current = new Date();
      if (current.getTime() - start.getTime() > 15000) { // max time in miliseconds
          //stops refresh
          clearInterval(interval);

          // lets them click on the link again
          myLink.attr('disabled', '');

          // resets the old img
          myImg.attr('src', 'oldImg.jpg');
      } else {
          // should be obvious
          myImg.attr('src', 'webcam/image.jpg?t=' + current.getTime()); 
      }
   }

   // refreshes page
   interval = setInterval(refresh, 500);

   refresh(); // don't wait for the first 1/2 second
});
```

Comment: You should use `.removeAttr('disabled')` here  :) Also, `.attr('disabled', true)` for consistency.

Comment: hi Terence.  Thanks very much for your answer.  It sounds perfectly correct to me! I can't seem to get it to work however.

Take a look at the site I am implementing this on: http://www.barsurferla.com/demo/bars/cocknbull/

Can you take a look at the source and see why it's not working? (your code is in the js/functions.js)

Comment: you really shouldn't have me doing your work for you... but since I'm nice... wrap the whole thing in $(function() {...code I wrote...});

Comment: my god Terence, you are my hero.  I've been trying to get this to work for months. Thank you thank you thank you.

Comment: glad to help... oh, and one other thing... you probably shouldn't have tagged this question as PHP (HTML maybe, though js is commonly used for webpages)